# A false integral inequality

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

I have a problem which I think is wrong.

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with $f'$ continuous such that $$\int_a^b f(x) d x = f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = 0$$
>
> Prove that $$\int_a^b \big(f'(x)\big)^2 d x - 2 \big(f(a) + f(b)\big)^2 \geq \frac{8}{(b-a)^2} \int_a^b \big(f(x)\big)^2 d x$$

If it's correct, can you show me your solution? Else, can you fix it?

Comment: What did you try ? What are your thoughts ?

Comment: Try $f(x)=(x-1/2)^2$, $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: $f(\frac{1}{2})=0$ in this case, but $\int_{0}^{1}(x- \frac{1}{2})^2 dx \neq 0$ (we must have $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=f(\frac{a+b}{2})$)

Comment: @LAHTNEKURB Why do you think the problem is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the proposed inequality is totally wrong. Indeed, consider
$$f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 18 |x|^{13/5} - 11 |x|^{6/5}$$
(so $a = -1, b = 1$.) Clearly $f$ has a continuous first derivative, and it is straightforward to check that 
$$\renewcommand{\intd}{\,\mathrm{d}} \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \intd x = 0 = f(0)$$
while $$A = \int_{-1}^1 \big(f'(x)\big)^2 \intd x - 2\big(f(-1) + f(1)\big)^2 = \frac{608}{35} \approx 17.37$$
and $$B = 2 \int_{-1}^1 \big(f(x)\big)^2 \intd x = \frac{11270}{527} \approx 21.385$$
So, the proposed inequality is wrong.

**A Family of Possible Corrections.**

Consider a function $f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) \intd x = 0 = f(0)$$
Note that
$$\renewcommand{\defeq}{~{\buildrel{\rm def}\over =}~}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}
A \defeq f(1) + f(-1) = \int_{-1}^1 \sgn(x) f'(x) \intd x$$
Let $\lambda$ be a real constant. Now we have
$$\int_{-1}^1 \big(f(x) - \lambda A\big)^2 \intd x = \int_{-1}^1 \big(f(x)\big)^2 \intd x + \lambda^2 A^2 \tag{1}$$
because $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) \intd x = 0$. On the other hand
$$f(x) - \lambda A = \int_0^x f'(t) \intd t - \lambda \int_{-1}^1 \sgn(t) f'(t) \intd t = \int_{-1}^1 K(x,t) f'(t) \intd t$$
where $K(x,t)$ is defined as follows:

- If $x\geq 0$, $$K(x,t) = \begin{cases}
      \lambda & t \leq 0 \\
      1 - \lambda & 0 < t \leq x \\
      -\lambda & x < t \leq 1
    \end{cases}$$
- If $x< 0$, $$K(x,t) = \begin{cases}
      \lambda & t \leq x \\
      \lambda - 1 & x < t \leq 0 \\
      -\lambda & 0 < t
    \end{cases}$$

Thus, using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\big(f(x) - \lambda A\big)^2 \leq \int_{-1}^1 \big(K(x,t)\big)^2 \intd t \int_{-1}^1 \big(f'(t)\big)^2 \intd t$$
So,
$$\int_{-1}^1 \big(f(x) - \lambda A\big)^2 \intd x \leq \int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_{-1}^1 \big(K(x,t)\big)^2 \intd t\right) \intd x \cdot \int_{-1}^1 \big(f'(t)\big)^2 \intd t$$
The calculations are not hard and we get
$$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_{-1}^1 \big(K(x,t)\big)^2 \intd t\right) \intd x = 1 - 2 \lambda + 4 \lambda^2$$
That is
$$\int_{-1}^1 \big(f(x) - \lambda A)^2 \intd x \leq (1 - 2 \lambda + 4 \lambda^2) \cdot \int_{-1}^1 \big(f'(t)\big)^2 \intd t \tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we finally get

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \big(f(x)\big)^2 \intd x + \lambda^2 \big(f(1) + f(-1)\big)^2 \leq (1 - 2 \lambda + 4 \lambda^2) \cdot \int_{-1}^1 \big(f'(t)\big)^2 \intd t \tag{3}
$$

For example, if $\lambda = 1/4$, we obtain
$$\int_{-1}^1 \big(f(x)\big)^2 \intd x + \frac{1}{16}\big(f(1) + f(-1)\big)^2 \leq \frac{3}{4} \cdot \int_{-1}^1 \big(f'(t)\big)^2 \intd t$$

**Remark.** The case of a function $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is obtained by applying the preceding case to $g(x) = f\left(\frac{a + b}{2} + x \frac{b-a}{2}\right)$.

**Remark.** In fact, there is a more subtle reason why the proposed inequality cannot be true. Consider for $a < b$ and a function $f$ with continuous derivative on $[a,b]$ the quantity
$$\Delta(a, b; f) = \int_a^b \big(f'(x)\big)^2 \intd x - 2 (f(a) + f(b))^2 - \frac{8}{(b-a)^2} \int_a^b \big(f(x)\big)^2 \intd x$$
Now, for $\lambda > 0$ and $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ we define $f_\lambda$ to be
the function defined on $\left[\frac{a}{\lambda}, \frac{b}{\lambda}\right]$ by 
$f_\lambda(x)=f(\lambda x)$.
With this notation we have
$$\Delta\left(\frac{a}{\lambda}, \frac{b}{\lambda}; f_\lambda\right) = \lambda \Delta(a, b; f) + 2 (\lambda - 1) \big(f(a) + f(b)\big)^2$$
So, if $f(a) + f(b) \ne 0$, there is always $\lambda, \Lambda > 0$ where the inequality holds for $f_\lambda$ and does not hold for  $f_\Lambda$.

Comment: Your example is not a counterexample of the problem because $f'$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The only exception is at $x=0$ this is superfluous and clearly $f$  can be approximated by $C^\infty$ functions. Note that only the integrability of $f'$ is needed.

Comment: The problem is completely solved only if you prove that the function which you use to approximate $f$ satisfies all conditions.

Comment: @Spenser, Your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. I also got a working counterexample by taking your first example $f(x)=3x^2-2|x|$ but replacing the absolute value of $x$ by the smooth function $cx\frac{e^{10x}-1}{e^{10x}+1}$ for some constant $c$. Adjusting $c$ we get $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx=0$ and then then proposed inequality becomes $0.340164\geq 0.43778$.

Comment: @OmranKouba Can you please tell me, how you figured this out?

Comment: @LAHTNEKURB, I do not know if you mean the counter example or the whole thing. If you mean the counter-example, just compare the current example with $7(3x^2-2|x|)$ to see that they are very close. But, if you mean the whole thing, well it took me some time.

Comment: I mean the counterexample.

Comment: Thank you sir for the effort!

Comment: @LAHTNEKURB, For the counter-example, I tried to look for a function for which the left side of your inequality is $0$, and this yields something proportional to  $x\mapsto3x^2-2|x|$.

Answer (score 5):

Omran Kouba's answer is very good, but here is a perhaps simpler counterexample. Take
$$f:[-2,2]\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=x^2(x^2-12/5).$$
Then,
$$\int_{-2}^2f(x)dx=f(0)=0,$$
but
$$\int_{-2}^2f'(x)^2dx-2(f(-2)+f(2))^2=-\frac{19456}{175}<\frac{8}{(2-(-2))^2}\int_{-2}^2f(x)^2dx=\frac{47104}{7875}.$$

Comment: In view of your answer, I think you would like my second remark.